# Is it possible to track two values on different time frames with pine script?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I have trouble testing a strategy on TradingView with pine script.

I have a strategy entry when MA 9 crosses above MA 5 in a timeframe of 1 hour. That's no problem, just write the script and change time to 1 hour on TradingView.

However, the strategy also enters only when RSI is greater than 60 in a timeframe of 15 minutes.

Is it possible to test this strategy on tradingview with pine script if I am tracking things in different times? I am tracking MA on 1 hour and tracking RSI on 15 minutes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
src = input(title="Source", type=input.source, defval=close)
rsiLength= input(title="  RSI Length", type=input.integer, defval=14, minval=1, 
 maxval=1000)

F_RSI(source, rsiLength) => 
    r= 0.0, r:= rsi(source, rsiLength)
    r

resolution_RSI(tf)=>
    p= security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, F_RSI(src, rsiLength))
    p

tf1=input("15",type=input.resolution,title="Select timeframe 
",group="Timeframe")
rsi_15_min_val=resolution_RSI(tf1)
```

you can use this function to get another timeframe rsi value.